# Strange empty APFS container

Tags: macos

If I enter `diskutil list` there is a strange container:

```
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Daten    312.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 91.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.2 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume                         14.0 GB    disk1s7
```

This `disk1s7` is also listed (greyed out) in the `Disk utility.app`. I cannot activate it.

If I try to mount it with `diskutil mount disk1s7` I get the error:

```
Volume on disk1s7 failed to mount
Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)
This appears to be an APFS Volume; note that locked APFS volumes
will not mount unless unlocked (e.g. "diskutil apfs unlockVolume")
```

If I type in `diskutil apfs unlockVolume disk1s7` I need to enter a passphrase. I don't know anyone that could work, if I type in just sth. I get:

```
Unlocking any cryptographic user on APFS Volume disk1s7
Error unlocking APFS Volume: The given APFS Volume is not encrypted (-69593)
```

Any ideas? Can I just delete it?

Comment: Partitions don't just show up out of no where.  Were you trying to make changes?  Were you trying to install something?  If so, what exactly?  Can you just delete it?  Yes.  But what the ramifications will be depends on what was being done with it.

Comment: This looks like the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/397302/update-container-on-macos - so, what did you do to it between one question & the next?

Comment: It's not the same issue.... the output was the same in the other question I just took out the strange container not to make a confusion. As I wrote there: I installed Big Sur beta on a newly created container, that's all I did.